# Does the EclEmma coverage tool perform node or edge or condition or path coverage?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, eclemma

I have a question about EclEmma coverage tool,

Does the EclEmma coverage tool perform node or edge or condition or path
coverage? Explain

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

EclEmma - is Eclipse plugin based on Java Code Coverage Library called [JaCoCo](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/) that performs analysis of Java bytecode. Description of coverage counters provided by JaCoCo [can be found in its documentation](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html). As you can see in it - JaCoCo and hence EclEmma provide

- instructions coverage
- branch coverage
- line coverage
- and cyclomatic complexity

Don't know what you call node coverage, and I'm guessing that what you call edge coverage - is branch coverage.

Regarding condition coverage - [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage)

> ```
> if (a && b) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> condition coverage can be satisfied by two tests `a=true, b=false`, `a=false, b=true`

what seems a bit weird in case of Java where `&&` is a short-circuit operator - second test can't trigger retrieval of value of "b".

Regarding path coverage - JaCoCo does not provide it, what can be demonstrated using following example:

```
void fun(boolean a, boolean b) {
  if (a) { /* ... */ }
  if (b) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Not counting exception there are 4 paths thru this method. And so for full path coverage 4 tests will be required - `a = true, b = true`, `a = true, b = false`, `a = false, b = true` and `a = false, b = false`. However JaCoCo and EclEmma would report 100% coverage after just 2 tests - `a = true, b = true` and `a = false, b = false`.